# Error C2593: 'operator >>' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I had obtained this error while overloading the >> operator, and I have no idea why.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& stream, unsigned int in)
{
    stream >> in;
    //manyoperators
    if(in>10)
       in = -1;
    return stream;
}
```

Part of code with error:

```
unsigned int tmm;
    cin >> tmm;
```

Why? I have no other overloading of >>.
What it may be?

Comment: Why do you assign `-1` to an unsigned int?

Comment: `stream >> in` would cause infinite recursion anyway.

Comment: amm about -1)
it's mistake)
for example it may be 0.

Comment: 2 eidolon:
why?
it simply saves data wrom stream to variable in

Comment: @user1887783 the code `stream >> in` calls this overloaded function you're defining, from within itself -- you're overloading it so that it will do precisely that; that's why it would cause infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload functions(in your case operator `>>`) for only custom classes not inbuilt data types.
The C++ standard library itself provides overloads for inbuilt data types.

Comment: Close, but `istream` **is** a custom class and not an inbuilt data type.

Comment: @Robᵩ close, but `istream` is not the inbuilt data type that is the problem, `unsigned int` is ;)

Comment: May I to overload operator for reading unsigned int?
or there're no variants to do it?

Comment: @user1887783 not directly; when you overload an existing function you _must_ change its signature (its input parameters) in some non-ambiguous way. You can come close if you create your own class that contains an unsigned int data member but you would also have to do quite a bit more to make it function as if it were a numeric type directly. Even if you could do what you're asking, you would likely not truly want to -- do you think you would want input to _all_ unsigned ints to function in this special manner? Looks like you're trying to filter user input in much too elegant a manner.

Comment: Yes i want to do it.
It is closely to handling exception.
But in other way.
The program must prevent the inputting of chars instead digits.
How may i do it?

Answer (score 0):

`std::istream` has `operator>>(unsigned int&)` as a member. The compiler can't choose whether to invoke the member function (defined in `<iostream>`) or the free function which you wrote.